# autocmd not being executed when opening file

Tags: vimrc, autocmd, folding

I've added the following lines to my .vimrc after reading about folding the other day (taken from vim.wikia.com):

```
autocmd Syntax html,python,tex setlocal foldmethod=indent
autocmd Syntax html,python,tex normal zR
```

I wanted indented folds enabled, but to be open when I first open a file. However, when I open a python file all the folds are closed, and when I open a .tex file all the folds are open.

Does anyone know what the problem is here?

Comment: Seems to work for me for Python files when I add those two lines. There is probably another setting, autocommand, or plugin in your vimrc that is causing the behaviour. Try following the steps in [how do I debug my vimrc file?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51) to find out what it is. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/q/1325/51)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I don't have any plugins installed, I'll try commenting out everything in my vimrc and seeing if that fixes it.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I've commented out everything except those two lines and now I get `E490: No fold found` where previously it was being folded. With just `filetype on` and `filetype indent on`, still no folding (and that error). But as soon as I add `filetype plugin on` the problem returns.

Comment: I suspect that changing `Syntax` to `Filetype` will make it work? This is probably due to the loading order of things...

Comment: If changing to `Filetype` doesn't help, try putting both commands in a single autocmd (or better, in ftplugins): `autocmd Filetype html,python,tex setlocal foldmethod=indent | normal zR`. This is just a hunch, but I don't know if Vim offers any guarantees about what order autocmds will be triggered in.

Comment: @Rich According to [`:help :autocmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#%3aautocmd) "in the order in which they were given". This is also repeated later: "Vim executes all matching autocommands in the order that you specify them".

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Thanks for the correction. I skimmed the help before writing that comment, but somehow missed both of those.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Changing Syntax to Filetype worked. If you want to put that as an answer I can accept it.